# double.ToString("F") System.FormatException in mscorelib.dll

Tags: c#, tostring, fixed-point

I have C# code which converts a double with a large amount of decimal places to a string using fixed point formatting and displays it in a textbox. Here is an example:

```
stringReadTextBox.AppendText("Test Altitude = " +T.Altitude.ToString("F") + Environment.NewLine)
```

where T.Altitude is a double which looks something like 45.99999999999999999999999999 but ranges from approximately 30 to 210 always with a large number of decimal places (this is due to the device's firmware I am getting the number from).

I use .ToString("F") to format it in order to make it more readable. However, after about 300 - 600 iterations of this I will randomly get a

> System.FormatException in mscorelib.dll

Why is this happening?

My code runs fine and doesn't stop when the exception happens but I want to clean it up. It wasn't happening until I added the "F" formatting property.

Before when it was just `T.Altitude.ToString()` it never happened.

Could it be a result of too many decimal places?

It is a multi threaded program so I am not sure how to catch the exception in detail, I have a try-catch block around the bulk of the code but that is as detailed of information as I am getting.

I tried searching for similar posts but cannot find any related to such a specific case.

There is never a null being converted to string so I know it is not that.

Other posts I saw have it happen every time, mine only occurs after a few hundred iterations of that line. Please request more info before down voting my question as I have hardly an rep.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a [mcve]? What version of the framework is this targeting? Anything you can do to help us reproduce it would help.

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is being caused by that single line of code shown? You did mention about its a multi-threaded program, yet the text box is a GUI control... it sounds like a code smell that is occuring elsewhere.

Comment: Framework is version 4.5.2. I am not able easily to reproduce in a Minimal example, it requires thousands of lines of codes to get the numbers I am formatting from the device (GPIB communication from multiple devices)..at least I am not able to easily do this without writing a new and simplified program which would require time I do not have, this is for industry production. I can do it if I absolutely have to but would be best to avoid. I am 99% sure the exception is from that line of code because it wasn't occurring until I added the "F" condition.

Comment: The GUI control is being referenced from a worker thread..full line of code is this.InvokeEx(f => f.stringReadTextBox.AppendText("Test Altitude = " +(T.Altitude - 45) + Environment.NewLine));

Comment: closet way to reproduce I can think of is create a loop that converts a double with very large number of decimal places to a string over several hundred iterations using this formatting. I have about 9 months C# experience so forgive me as I am not an expert in debugging

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error by running the same code through several hundred iterations, it occurs randomly, sometimes not at all though.

Comment: mostly I am wondering is it  possible to create this format exception from double.ToString("F")?

Comment: I removed all instances of "F" in .ToString() to verify if the problem still exists. Running the code now. I will be gone for a few days after 30 mins of testing

Comment: I will not be able to provide any updates until Monday. Please do not down vote in the mean time. Thank you for your help

Comment: after hundreds of iterations I have yet to receive the exception after removing the "F." There seems to be an odd truncation error going on with this device generating the data. Here is what the manufacturer's software development team told me word for word (this same issue is causing me invalid value exceptions in the ASCOM drivers which interface with the iOptron telescopic mount's firmware which is generating these exceptionally long decimals which I am trying to format:

Comment: From iOptron: “ It seems the interval between the commands is too short, resulting in the motherboard could not reply on time occasionally. The suggested time interval for a round of commands inquiries and executions is 1 second.
 
The truncating or carrying over the decimal point is out of our control. The issue that 5 + 0.1 = 5.10000000001 is likely caused by the combination of compiler and data types. A “double” data means that the effective digits could be 18 ~ 19 bits. It is widely found that in various compilers, the floating point operation will cause these kind of slight inaccuracy."

Comment: this issue of extra decimal points only occurs when I increment with 0.1 but NEVER with 0.5 increments. They said they have no control over it and to format the output data (which is obviously not working out for me). I don't believe they have no control over it

Comment: I doubt this `FormatException` thrown from `ToString()`. Looking into the native code, the only chance to throw `FormatException` in `ToString()` is when you specify wrong format specifier. Please see https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp#L1593. Please: 1. try to extract your `T.Altitude.ToString("F") ` and execute it alone to see if this exception can occur. 2. Print all the generated double numbers until the exception thrown. The last generated double number should be the one which cause the exception.